# Temporarily disable internet connection on a system

Tags: linux, command-line, internet

Is there any way to temporarily "switch off (and back on)" the internet connection on a system (that runs linux)? The following methods are not allowed:

1. Turning off the router. That would lead to a lot of angry young individuals. This method must be particular to my workstation.
2. Use root privileges (coz I do not have them).
3. Yank the ethernet cable from the system.

Why: Sometimes the internet proves to be a distraction.

I am using the following system: Fedora release 11 (Leonidas), linux kernel 2.6.30 and GNOME 2.26.3

Answer (score 0):

What version of linux are you using? There is a page on the ubuntu help that goes into disabling a network adaptor..

https://help.ubuntu.com/8.04/internet/C/networking-disable.html

Comment: you need root for

Comment: @bestsss - ah thanks, surely you must need to sudo and know the password then?

Comment: @WraithNath: Added information about system to question.